# WPF: Get next /prev visual object

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `StackPanel` containing a number of`TextBox`.  Is there a way to get the Next / Previous visual elements ?

The functionality I want is fairly analogous to jQuery's  `.next()` function that get the next object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following  method to enumerate the Visual Tree.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>
(DependencyObject depObj, string childName) where T : DependencyObject
{

    if (depObj != null)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
        {

            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
            if (child != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
            {
                yield return (T)child;
            }

            foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child, childName))
            {
                yield return childOfChild;
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Assuming that you named your textBoxes `"tbInsideStackPanel"`, use it like:

```
foreach (var textBox in FindVisualChildren<TextBox>(this.stackPanel1, 
              "tbInsideStackPanel").ToList())
{
   textBox.Background = Brushes.Blue;
}
```